Converting a custom footnote to a continuous numbered footnote list
I have some footnotes that I am editing (on a Mac), which have cross-references to the footnote (so copying and pasting the footnote text into a newly inserted footnote is not really an option).
How would I convert a custom footnote mark to a continuously numbered list (see below image)

I would like to be able to convert 8a, 9a, 9b, and 10a to their corresponding numbered footnote (without letters) such that the above footnotes would just number from 9–16:
8a --> 9
9a --> 11
9b --> 12
10a --> 14

I have heard that it's possible to convert the footnotes without copying and pasting by following these steps:

Place your cursor at the end of the content of footnote 8a.
Right-click on the footnote reference number (in this case, 8a) at the bottom of the page.
Select "Edit Field" from the context menu.
In the Field dialog box, change the "Reference type" to "Footnote" and set the "Field properties" to the desired footnote number (in this case, 9).
Click OK to apply the changes.

However, I am not able to confirm (at least on PC). For Mac, there is no option to edit field, and my understanding of the footnote dialog box (when right-clicking) is limited and has been futile in changing the footnote back to a continuous list.
What would I have to do on Mac to change the footnote mark back to a continuous list?

I believe you will get faster and better help on either https://superuser.com/ or https://answers.microsoft.com/
